# What's the use of vendor folder?

Tags: 8

Whats the use of vendor folder in drupal 8, what it actually do ?

Comment: Vendor is a folder... any specific file in it?

Comment: I am just asking vendor folder creates in our drupal root directory ,what it actually do ,not asking about any specific file.

Comment: The Vendor folder stores php packages/libraries, that are not Drupal related, that Drupal core & contrib modules make use of.

Answer (score 3):

"vendor" is the folder where a Drupal - composer Installation stores it's libraries. If you look at the file web/autoload.php you'll find how that works.

Don't care. It's what's called the "External Libraries" in a java project.